# Need all submenus to reside under first nav option; last submenu option has different width

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, nav, submenu

So, two issues here:

**First:** So I want to make a nav structure where the **first ul** tree is a normal horizontal nav bar, and the **second ul** tree is a single vertical navbar residing beneath the first option from the **first ul** tree (essentially all portions of the submenu would reside within the same location, replacing the previous submenu **ul** once another one is activated).

I've gotten it to work on a base level here, though I figure there has to be a better way to do this than the method I've chosen of manually adjusting the **right** element, especially because **I need this to match on multiple screen sizes** (including, for example, an **iPad** screen size [**I'm using jQuery Mobile**]).

**Second:** The final **li** within all of the submenus (except for the last one, for whatever reason) has a longer width than the rest of the **li's**.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <!--Normal CSS Stylsheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css">

    <!--jQuery Mobile Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <!--FooTable CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/FooTable-2/css/footable.core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/FooTable-2/css/footable.metro.css">

    <!--jQuery Library-->
    <script src="includes/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!--jQuery Mobile Library-->
    <script src="includes/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <!--Footable jQuery-->
    <script src="includes/FooTable-2/js/footable.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/FooTable-2/js/footable.sort.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/FooTable-2/js/footable.filter.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/FooTable-2/js/footable.paginate.js"></script>

    <!--General Javascript-->
    <script src="includes/js/general.js"></script>

</head>
<body>   
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="home">


        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<nav id="navbar" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Real-Time</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
                <li class="lastFirstNav"><a href="#">Choice 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="pageChange">Database Functions</a>
            <ul class="secondNav">
                <li><a href="#">Another Choice 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another Choice 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="pageChange">Settings/Configuration</a>
            <ul class="thirdNav">
                <li><a href="login.php">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Third Choice 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Third Choice 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A Third Choice 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>


        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>
                Home
            </h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
}

#navbar ul ul li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#navbar ul ul.secondNav li 
{
    right: 100%;
}


#navbar ul ul.thirdNav li
{
    right: 200.5%;
}

    #navbar ul ul li a.active {
        background: #4b545f;
    }

#navbar ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top: 0;
}

#navbar ul li.active > ul { 
        display: block;
    }

#navbar ul li { 
    float: left;
}

#navbar ul li.active {

    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}

#navbar ul li a {
    display:block; 
    padding: 25px 40px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks.

Update: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLx7vgjo/3/

Comment: I tried running your code on a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LLx7vgjo/ and the submenus aren't appearing? Is there any external resource you're missing that you can link in?

Comment: Sorry @Douglas I forgot about the JavaScript and fixed a few things that were messed up in the original code. Check the post for a new JSFiddle.

Comment: Your last li item width difference is caused by jquery-mobile applying  `.ui-navbar li:last-child .ui-btn {margin-right: -4px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the submenus to line up on the left then position them relative to the main top `ul` not the child `li`.

```
#navbar > ul {
    position: relative;
}

 #navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: auto; 
}
```

As for the width, the submenus will only be as wide as they need to be (`width:auto`) to contain their various `li` and links.

This will be different for each submenu as the content of those links will vary with the content.

If you want consistency, define a width on the submenu `ul`.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLx7vgjo/6/)